# how to loop through an array of objects and create a json object?

Tags: json, swift

I have an array of 300 objects which each object contain many parameters and I want to loop through the array to create a JSON object which contain only two parameters. my objects were created from this json structure in the array :

```
 "publicationId": 13,
            "name": null,
            "code": "FIGA_20190516",
            "parutionDate": "2019-05-16",
            "quadri": "FIGA",
            "ratio": null,
            "numero": "0",
            "createdAt": "2019-06-18 21:29:21",
            "nbPages": 0,
            "search": 1,
            "down": 1,
            "thumb_height": 0,
            "quartPageWidth": 0,
            "quartPageHeight": 0,
            "pdfHeight": "0",
            "pdfWidth": "0",
            "PDF": "2019-06-18 21:29:21",
            "XML": null,
            "SendKM": "2019-06-18 21:29:21",
            "KM": null,
            "Melody": null,
            "filename": null,
            "SendNormalize": null,
            "Normalized": null,
            "librelioSubTitle": null,
            "SendProcessArticle": null,
            "ProcessedArticles": null,
            "melodyCallBackUrl": null,
            "htmlMilibris": false,
            "htmlHarry": false,
            "sendProcessLibrelio": null,
            "processedLibrelio": null,
            "id": 77066,
            "_solrDocument": {},
            "_repository": "FIGA/2019/05/FIGA_20190516/"
```

and I want to loop through the array to create a JSON object with this struct :

```
"availableParutions" : {
        id : createdAt,
        id : createdAt,
        id : createdAt
    }
```

I really appreciate your help guys !

Comment: Hi @mark, where did you get JSON data? Service or is it involved in the project?

Comment: Have you checked `Codable`?

Comment: Is it the same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081141/how-to-parse-array-of-json-to-array-in-swift?

Comment: Hi @Emre it's a service

Comment: hey @Ahmed nope it's not the same structure I can create a structure of array of objects [{obj},{obj},{obj}] like the exemple you posted but this is an other format {key:value, key:value, key:value}

Comment: Make your struct conform to `Encodable` and implement the `encode` function or create a new struct with only two properties that conforms to `Encodable` and that is created from the large struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new struct that represents the data you want in your Json output

```
struct NewStruct: Encodable {
    let id: Int
    let createAt: String
}
```

This struct conforms to Encodable so that it can be encoded to json but since it is so simple no extra coding is needed

Then you can convert your array of large objects to an array of `NewStruct` using `map`

```
let newArray = array.map { NewStruct(id: $0.id, createAt: $0.createdAt) }
```

If I understand it correctly this array should be a property named "availableParutions" so lets make an outer struct for the json

```
struct Output: Codable {
    let availableParutions: [NewStruct]
}
```

and load it

```
let output = Output(availableParutions: newArray)
```

and encode it

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(output)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Joakim you saved me !

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

Note: I have create json obj my self for evaluation purpose, you can use your json directly.

```
    let json = [
        [
        "publicationId":11,
        "createdAt":"2019-06-18 21:29:21",
        "id":77063,
        ],
        [
            "publicationId":12,
            "createdAt":"2019-06-18 21:29:21",
            "id":77065,
        ],
        [
            "publicationId":13,
            "createdAt":"2019-06-18 21:29:21",
            "id":77066,
        ]
        ]

 var jsonArr: [[String:Any]] = [[String:Any]]()
        for obj in json {
            let id = obj["id"] as! Int
            let jsonObj = [
                "\(id)": obj["createdAt"] as! String
            ]
            jsonArr.append(jsonObj as [String : Any])
        }
        print(jsonArr)
```

Comment: Hey @Bhavik ! thank you for your reply, so first my array dosen't contain json it contain objects created from the passed json format, second I tested your code and it gives me this format:[["77063": "2019-06-18 21:29:21"], ["77065": "2019-06-18 21:29:21"], ["77066": "2019-06-18 21:29:21"]] and it don't match the format I want, thank you for your try

Answer (score 0):

You could create an empty dictionary, then iterate over json array and pull out `id` & `createdAt`. Update dictionary with `id` & `createdAt`. Finally set this dictionary as value of `availableParutions` in a new dictionary.

code:

```
    var map: [Int: Any]  = [:]
    for item in json {
        let id = item["id"] as! Int
        map[id] = item["createdAt"]!
    }
    let outerObject = ["availableParutions": map]
    print(outerObject)
```