# Converting a JSValue to a typed array

Tags: swift

I'm writing a tvos app and it has a function that my tvml calls with an array of objects.

How do I properly cast the json to an array of some type/interface?

```swift
// This type is generated from my TypeScript types
struct Video: Codable {
    let title: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
    }
}

{
      func appController(_ appController: TVApplicationController, evaluateAppJavaScriptIn jsContext: JSContext) {
        let playVideo : @convention(block) (Int, JSValue) -> Void = {
            (start, json) -> Void in
            // How do I properly cast the json to an array of Videos?
            let playlist = json;

            for video in playlist {
                // here I would like to access video.title
                print(video)
            }
        }

        jsContext.setObject(unsafeBitCast(playVideo, to: AnyObject.self),
                            forKeyedSubscript: "playVideo" as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol))
    }
}
```

PS: I am very much a swift/objc newbie.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse Array of JSON to array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081141/how-to-parse-array-of-json-to-array-in-swift)

Comment: This seems to be ready from a file which is a little different. It has to be this JSValue type (I think) which is converted into swift types.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. It seems like I just need to use `AnyHashable`

```swift
let playlist = json.toArray() as! [[AnyHashable:Any]];

for video in playlist {
  print(video[AnyHashable("title")])
}
```

Although this still doesn't use my defined type